# insufficient cache for OrientDB

Tags: database, caching, installation, orientdb

during the install of OrientDB, i had an error saying that I have no sufficient memory to run the application ( according to its current configuration ) and asking me to change the maximum cache usage memory limit for the application by using the command -Xmx on java:

```
    2015-11-19 13:28:38:658 WARNI Not enough physical memory available for `enter code here`DISKCACHE: 2.006MB (heap=455MB). Set lower Maximum Heap (-Xmx setting on JVM) and restart OrientDB. Now running with DISKCACHE=256MB [orientechnologies]
2015-11-19 13:28:38:660 INFO OrientDB config DISKCACHE=-497MB (heap=455MB os=2.006MB disk=54.664MB) [orientechnologies]
2015-11-19 13:28:38:786 INFO Loading configuration from: /home/jeferson/orientdb-community-2.1.5/config/orientdb-server-config.xml... [OServerConfigurationLoaderXml]
2015-11-19 13:28:39:149 INFO OrientDB Server v2.1.5 (build 2.1.x@r; 2015-10-29 16:54:25+0000) is starting up... [OServer]
2015-11-19 13:28:39:210 INFO Databases directory: /home/jeferson/orientdb-community-2.1.5/databases [OServer]
2015-11-19 13:28:39:275 INFO Listening binary connections on 0.0.0.0:2424 (protocol v.32, socket=default) [OServerNetworkListener]
2015-11-19 13:28:39:281 INFO Listening http connections on 0.0.0.0:2480 (protocol v.10, socket=default) [OServerNetworkListener]
2015-11-19 13:28:39:307 INFO Installing dynamic plugin 'studio-2.1.zip'... [OServerPluginManager]
2015-11-19 13:28:39:447 INFO Installing GREMLIN language v.2.6.0 - graph.pool.max=50 [OGraphServerHandler]
2015-11-19 13:28:39:447 INFO [OVariableParser.resolveVariables] Error on resolving property: distributed [orientechnologies]
2015-11-19 13:28:39:451 INFO Installing Script interpreter. WARN: authenticated clients can execute any kind of code into the server by using the following allowed languages: [sql] [OServerSideScriptInterpreter]
2015-11-19 13:28:39:452 INFO OrientDB Server v2.1.5 (build 2.1.x@r; 2015-10-29 16:54:25+0000) is active. [OServer]
```

The problem is that seems it is necessary point the command to some class or jarfile, but they dont say what is, anyway I tried the jarfiles orientdb-core-2.1.5.jar and orientdb-core-2.1.5.jar.

So I got the following errors:

nenhum atributo de manifesto principal em /home/jeferson/orientdb-community-2.1.5/lib/orientdb-core-2.1.5.jar

```
    java -Xmx300m -jar /home/jeferson/orientdb-community-2.1.5/lib/orientdb-  server-2.1.5.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/orientechnologies/orient/core/exception/OConfigurationException
at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServerMain.create(OServerMain.java:26)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServerMain.main(OServerMain.java:40)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OConfigurationException
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
```

Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: I found an aproach, looking for the file orientdb-server-config.xml I found links to java classes, I can change them directly or find the jarfile where they are and change them.

Answer (score 4):

If you take a closer look at the output, you'll see the message is classified as WARNING, not an error.  This message is trying to convey that there is not enough free system RAM to support the default size of the "disk cache" that OrientDB creates.  The disk cache is actually system RAM that OrientDB creates and uses separately from the JVM heap.

I'm not sure exactly what calculation OrientDB uses for choosing the default size of the disk cache, but it is based on the JVM heapsize setting, which is why it's saying to lower the heap size.

You'll also see in the message that it chose a smaller size for the diskcache.  OrientDB will continue to function with this smaller diskcache size, but the warning indicates that maybe performance will not be optimal.